# Component contributions in Additive Model Time Series

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, seasonality, trend, shapley-value

I have trained a model for forecasting time series in a greedy procedure:

- Fit the Trend component T(t) of the series on the original signal y(t)
- Fit a Cyclical/Seasonal S(t) component of the series on the residual of the signal : RT(t) = y(t) - T(t)
- Fit an auto-regressive component E(t) on the residual : RS(t) = y(t) - RT(t)

Then my model for forecasting is :
f(t) = T(t) + S(t) + E(t)

I would like to quantify the importance of each of the three components with respect to:

- The predicted values of the forecast
- The forecast error

Would you have any idea as to how I could assess the contributions ?

My first idea was to compute the Shapley values of each of the three components but this approach prooved unsuccessful for the two following reasons:

- The Shapley value in an additive cooperative game is simply the individual component, hence no additionnal information is gained here
- The Shapley value computed on the Mean Squared Error does not work as in the definition of Shapley Value, the cooperative game characteristic function needs to satisfy v(∅) = 0 which is not the case for the MSE.